# I want to get the elements that are not present in array 1 but present in array 2

Tags: php

I have 2 arrays.

```
$first = [
    '01/10/2019' =>
        [
            21498226,
            21497647,
            21497649,
            21497635,
            21497636,
            21497637,
            21497728,
            21497822,
            21498028,
            21497638,
        ],
];

$second = [
    '01/10/2019' =>
        [
            21498226,
            21497647,
            12345678,
            87654321,
            21497636,
            21497637,
            21497728,
            21497822,
            21498028,
            21497638,
        ],
];
```

I have written this code

```
$notPresent = [];
foreach ($second as $date => $code) {
    foreach ($code as $c) {
        if (array_key_exists($date, $first)) {
            if (!in_array($c, $first[$date])) {
                $notPresent[$date] = $code;
            }
        } else {
            $notPresent[$date] = $code;
        }
    }
}
```

But it is returning me all 10 values. What I really want is to have only those values that are not present in $first. Like 12345678 and 87654321.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swap the arrays around so that you are looking for elements of array 2 that are not in array 1, and that's word-for-word what [`array_diff`](https://www.php.net/array-diff) does.

> returns the values in array1 that are not present in any of the other arrays

You will need to iterate over the "parent" arrays, naturally, so [`array_map`](https://www.php.net/array-map) can help too. (Although, to preserve the keys, you'll need some fiddling around with [`array_keys`](https://www.php.net/array-keys) and [`array_combine`](https://www.php.net/array-combine) since `array_map` doesn't preserve keys...)

```
$notPresent = array_combine(
    array_keys($second),
    array_map('array_diff', $second, $first)
);
```

---

EDIT I just realised that the above code assumes that the keys exist in both arrays in the same order. Since that's almost certainly not the case, here's an adjusted version that handles that.

```
$notPresent = array_combine(
    array_keys($second),
    array_map(function($key,$values) use ($first) {
        if( array_key_exists($key,$first)) {
            return array_diff($values, $first[$key]);
        }
        return $values;
    }, array_keys($second), array_values($second))
);
```

Comment: Woah that is the best explanation. I didn't know about array_diff. Thankyou so much. Exactly what I needed.

Comment: @AliZia Please see updated post - I've adjusted it to make it work in case `$first` and `$second` don't have the exact same keys.

Comment: Well yeah there can be different keys in both the arrays.

Comment: Hi. There is a little issue in the script :p